# Is it possible to cure dandruff?

Tags: biochemistry

If dandruff is caused due to oleic acid released by fungi malassezia then is it possible to control it by applying any base in our scalp ? Since base nullify the effect of oleic acid or base cause any further hairloss complication?

Comment: isn't just anything possible in the future? What are you after?

Comment: It might be a better fit for [worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) but I am not sure

Comment: why did you totally change the question and post? Just leave this one closed as it was, and take your new question and post it as a new post.

Answer (score 1):

we already transfer memories with books and movies, If are talking about direct transfer then the answer is no, because different brains already have different patterns of connections, so even if you could somehow for an exact copy of a single small pattern to form in someone's brain it will interact with the rest of the brain if very different ways.